# Spring webFlux infinite recursion

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

So I'am trying Spring webFlux and have following code:

```
   @Override
public Flux<? extends AnimalDatabaseEntity> queryAnimals() {
    return async(animalsRepository.findAll().stream());
}

private <T> Flux<T> async(Stream<T> stream) {
    return Flux.fromStream(stream).publishOn(scheduler);
}
```

The problem that I get infinite recursion, because "**AnimalDatabaseEntity**" has field **animalFeatures**.

```
@Entity(name = "animals")
public class AnimalDatabaseEntity {

  @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "animal_type")
private AnimalType animalType;

@Column(name = "number_of_legs")
private Integer numberOfLegs;

@Column(name = "is_pet")
private boolean isPet;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "animalDatabaseEntity", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<AnimalFeatureEntity> animalFeatures;
}
```

I don't really get why this does not work???

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is `AnimalFeatureEntity` contains varaible of type `AnimalDatabaseEntity` which references back to `List<AnimalFeatureEntity>` while serializing thus causing an infinite recursion. 
 
You can prevent it by adding `@JsonIgnore` to `AnimalDatabaseEntity` if it suits your use case. 
However, if you wish to preserve the bidirectional relationship, then `@JsonManagedReference/@JsonBackReference` or `@JsonIdentityInfo` is the way to go.
For example usage, refer [this article](http://javasampleapproach.com/json/resolve-json-infinite-recursion-problems-working-jackson)